# How to change background color of NppFTP Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I would like to change the NppFTP Notepad++ Plugin background. 
[This is a Screenshot of my Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfq3K.jpg), I have set the Zenburn theme from `Menu Settings -> Style Configurator`. 

The ​​the programming languages and Search results area has the black background but the **NppFTP** not changed background to black. Why?
Is there a way to change the background of this panel to black?
Thank you!

Comment: If the developer of a plugin didn't add support for colouring the plugin window(s) then there is no way to accomplish this. NppExec as an example allows to set a background-colour for it's console window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit a [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=321962&atid=1353003) for NppFTP.

Comment: There's an enhancement request opened for the functionality here: https://github.com/ashkulz/NppFTP/issues/94 @Mustapha Aoussar If you want the functionality, please join that GitHub issue and let the maintainers know that you want the feature.